# "At least + NOT " ambiguity

Tags: double-negation

this sentences :

"The patient knows in advance what are the possible outcomes; without that knowledge quality cannot be measured (AT LEAST NOT from the patient perspective)."

is that mean that i can still measure quality by the patient perspective?

I assume that "at least" as negative meaning then there is "not" negative meaning again, so the part in bracket i can say : 
"but you can (measure) form the patient perspective"

i need expert opinion...
i feel that im in a paradox

Answer (score 1):

"At least" is not a negative. It means "at a minimum" or "not less than".

In the specific construct you are talking about the second part is a clarification of the first. Putting it in the positive you might write:

> Quality can always be measured, at least from the patient perspective.

This is equivalent to:

> Quality can always be measured (I mean it can from the patient perspective, and perhaps from other perspectives).

In the negative this becomes:

> Quality can not be measured, at least not from the patient perspective.

Which means:

> Quality can not be measured (I mean it can not from the patient perspective, and perhaps not from other perspectives).

Your sentence means:

> Without that knowledge, quality cannot be measured from the patient perspective. It might be able to be measured from other perspectives.

There is no ambiguity.

Comment: The patient knows in advance what are the possible outcomes; without that knowledge quality cannot be measured (AT LEAST NOT from the patient perspective)

Comment: Quality can certainly be measured without the patient knowing what could happen. But the patient would not be able to do it.

Comment: The patient knows in advance what are the possible outcomes; without that knowledge quality cannot be measured (AT LEAST NOT from the patient perspective)

so is that means that:

" i can measure quality, only if I have their perspective."

or :

"I cant measure quality if i only have their perspective"

Comment: @QualityNatzi the answer is a good one and adequately explains what you've requested. If you need an answer at a more basic level, perhaps you might try our other site [ell.se] instead?